# Incrementar ProgressBar mediante bucle ANDROID

Tags: android, progressbar, bucle-for

Tengo un splash screen el cual cuenta con un progressbar donde en un futuro realizare las comprobaciones de existencia de bd de la aplicacion etc. Pero ahora me gustaria entender el como hacer que dicha barra progrese por ejemplo mediante un bucle for.

Como seria el codigo que deberia añadir al actual para que en vez de esperar 3000ms para que pase del splash screen a la main activity. Tenga que rellenarse la progressbar en ese tiempo mediante un bucle

JAVA:

```
public class SplashScreenActivity extends Activity {

// Set the duration of the splash screen
private static final long SPLASH_SCREEN_DELAY = 3000;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Set portrait orientation
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);

    setContentView(R.layout.splash_screen);

    TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            // Start the next activity
            Intent mainIntent = new Intent().setClass(SplashScreenActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(mainIntent);

            // Close the activity so the user won't able to go back this
            // activity pressing Back button
            finish();
        }
    };

    // Simulate a long loading process on application startup.
    Timer timer = new Timer();
    timer.schedule(task, SPLASH_SCREEN_DELAY);
}
```

}

XML:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/splash_screenImView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:src="@drawable/splash_screen" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/splash_screenProgressBar"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginBottom="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

</LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define un parámetro `MAX_VALUE` para tu `ProgressBar` y guarda la referencia del `ProgressBar` en una variable global:

```
public ProgressBar splash_screenProgressBar;
public int MAX_VALUE = 30; // Aqui puedes poner el valor que desees
```

Ahora busca la referencia en el layout e inicializa tu ProgressBar:

```
splash_screenProgressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.splash_screenProgressBar);
splash_screenProgressBar.setMax(MAX_VALUE);
```

Ahora crea un Timer cualquiera, en lo personal me gusta mas este:

```
new CountDownTimer(3000, 100) {

       int progreso = 1; // Variable que va a ir aumentando del progreso
       @Override
       public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            splash_screenProgressBar.setProgress(progreso);
            progreso += (1);
       }

       @Override
       public void onFinish() {
           progress.setProgress(MAX_VALUE);
       }
   }.start();
```

Si te fijas, el `CountDownTimer` recibe dos `parámetros`. El primero es la **duración** y el segundo es **cada cuantos ms va a pasar para que entre a onTic**k. Quiere decir que el valor en el que va a ir aumentando el progress debe ser **proporcional al tiempo definido en para que entre al onTick** y aumente su valor.

En este ejemplo utilicé un valor de 30 para el `MAX_VALUE`, ya que `OnTick` se llamará 30 veces en 3 segundos y lo estoy aumentando con un valor de 1 cada vez. Porque entrará cada 0.10ms (100) según lo definí en los parámetros del timer. Cuando termine, en caso de que no se haya completado el progreso por quizás un mal cálculo o imprecisión, ya que solo acepta valores enteros el `.setProgress()` del progressBar, defino el Progreso como `MAX_VALUE` para completar el progreso de la barra. Puedes manejarlo con tu lógica como quieras.

Saludos.

Comment: funciona a la perfeccion ;D gracias